# Using scipy.optimize.minimize() to find root in interval - how to properly set bounds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to find the root of one function using minimize() within an interval. [In this example that means I want to find a value of $z$ that satisfies $1000*scipy.sin(z)-z=0$ in interval $z\in[eps,a]$]

If I understood correctly from the documentation, that means I have to use the bounds option. However, I get *ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds error*.

Here is my code:

```
import scipy 
import scipy.optimize
def f(z):
    return 1000*scipy.sin(z)-z
scipy.optimize.minimize(f, 2*eps, bounds=(eps,a))
```

And here's the full error message. [image: error]

Comment: `minimize` doesn’t find roots… it minimizes.  You *can* minimize *f*^2, but much better is to use a [root finder](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html).

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm using minimize because I want to be able to set intervals in which it searches for roots

Comment: So use `root_scalar(bracket=…)`.  `minimize` doesn’t let you “set intervals in which it searches for roots” because it **doesn’t search for roots**.

Comment: well yes, the idea is to find the minima of the absolute of my function, I just couldn't make it work to start with. root_scalar isn't recognised by my machine for some reason, I guess it was depreciated.

Comment: It’s not deprecated; it was just [added in 1.2.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.2.0.html).  In older versions, one usually starts with `brentq`.

Comment: @DavisHerring brentq doesn't work properly for this problem because it demands that the function at interval edges has different signs

Comment: By inspection, your function has a sign change across (pi/2000,1).  If you have a function too complicated to bracket and where `newton` (which needs no bracket) might take you off the end of your interval, you’re very likely to have difficulty minimizing f^2 as well—since it doesn’t know that the minimum is 0, it may simply fail to converge to any zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
import scipy 
import scipy.optimize

def f(z):
    return 1000*scipy.sin(z)-z
scipy.optimize.minimize(f, 2*eps, bounds=[(eps,a)])
```

Comment: This is still not a root finder.